# find minimum possible value of a given number if we only have two operations

Tags: math, breadth-first-search, greedy, number-theory

We have a number let say m and we have the given two operation and our task is to find out the minimum possible value of m with minimum number of steps to reach

Two Operations are

1. We can add the digit of the number ( will be counted as 1 step ).
2. We can add a fix number k ( which is given )

We can repeat the above operations any number of times.

For example : m = 11 and k = 13

output: 1 4 ( 1 is the minimum value and 4 is the number of steps)

11 + 13 = 24 ( 1 step) + 13 = 37 (1+1 = 2 step) = 3+7 = 10( 3 steps) = 1+0 = 1 (4 steps)

what I have tried?

So, as such questions are handled by BFS in such a way that we visit each and every node till we get the minimum ( i thought this is based on BFS correct me if i am wrong). I thought we do BFS till we get either the digitsum repeated or the same number but its exceeding bounds because the constraints of m and k are upto 10^10.

Is there something i can do to optimise my BFS or is something else i have to do, i mean should i use some other algorithm?

Just need some guidance regarding what else i can do!

Comment: Please elaborate on "but its exceeding bounds". What do you mean by it ? Also clarify what is the lower constrain of m and k.

Comment: @c0der lower bound is 1 for both m and k and "exceeding bounds" means the time limit is 1 sec and i am not able to code it in that time limit ( sorry for late response, College life is too busy)

Comment: This question is from an ongoing contest: https://www.codechef.com/OCT18B/problems/MINDSUM

Comment: Please add the vital information to the question. Also share your code and add a programming language tag.

Comment: To speed BFS you may want to add  heuristic . See [Dijkstra's algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dijkstra%27s_algorithm)